# How to get the request headers for particular url using selenium

Tags: python-3.x

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from seleniumwire import webdriver
import time
import requests
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
url = "https://premierrem.managebuilding.com/manager/public/authentication/login"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

find_email_field = driver.find_element_by_id("emailAddressInput")
find_email_field.send_keys("abc@gmail.com")
find_password_field = driver.find_element_by_id("passwordInput")
find_password_field.send_keys("abc@123")
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(text(), "Sign in")]').click()
time.sleep(20)
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Maintenance").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("lnk_Workorders").click()
print(driver.current_url)
for request in driver.requests:
  print(request.headers)
```

Is there any solution to get the request headers only from current url. My solution is getting the headers for all drivers url. I want the request header from driver.current_url

Comment: I have seen that but I need only the request header from driver.current_url

Comment: Something like:
```for request in driver.requests:
  if request.url == driver.current_url:
      print(request.headers) # <----------- Request headers
   print(request.response.headers) # <-- Response headers```